`latexmk` finds a "too many" compilation on one file
I use a bash file to launch latexmk on all the TeX files inside one folder that is analyzed recursively.
Some of my files need just two compilations, but latexmk wants compiles them more than 5 times, and it gives me the following error message. One of the problematic file can be found here : https://github.com/bc-writings/bc-public-docs/tree/science-tools/science-tools/latex-and-co/cookbook/src/science/math/misc/gauss-sum-trick/draft .
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'main.tex':
   'latex' needed too many passes
----------------------

I would like to tell to latexmk to compile this files only two times using a latexmkrc file for example. Is it possible?
# --------------- #
# -- CONSTANTS -- #
# --------------- #

THISDIR=$(dirname "$0")
WORKINGDIR=$(pwd)


# ----------------------- #
# -- ONE FOLDER NEEDED -- #
# ----------------------- #

if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    echo "CRITICAL - Missing arg: absolute target folder needed."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "CRITICAL - Too much arguments!"
    exit 1
fi

TARGET=$1

if [ ! -d "$TARGET" ]
then
    echo "CRITICAL - Missing folder: ''$TARGET''."
    exit 1
fi


# --------------------- #
# -- LISTED PROJECTS -- #
# --------------------- #

function nocompile {
    open "$1"
}

cd "$TARGET"

for f in $(find . -name '*.tex')
do
    fdir=$(dirname "$f")

    cd "$TARGET/$fdir"

    echo "-- NEW TEX FILE --"
    echo "$f"
    echo ""

    compilemode="lualatex --interaction=nonstopmode --halt-on-error --shell-escape %O %S"

    SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=0 FORCE_SOURCE_DATE=1 latexmk -quiet -pdf -pdflatex="$compilemode" "$TARGET/$f" || nocompile "$TARGET/$f"
done # for f in $(find . -name '*.tex')


How do you know they only need two compilations? Latexmk is usually quite good a using the minimal number of compilations.

$max_repeat=2; But I think preferable to trust latexmk.

@deleif: I just compile things by hand. The problematic code is here : https://github.com/bc-writings/bc-public-docs/tree/science-tools/science-tools/latex-and-co/cookbook/src/science/math/misc/gauss-sum-trick/draft .

@jlab: this is for small codes that are easy to check by hand.

lualatex main && lualatex main should do the work. Anyway, it would be preferable to fix the warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right. It triggers the rerun.

May I suggest changing the title of this question, since the issue isn't about stopping latexmk from compiling too many times but rather figuring out why it thought it should keep compiling.

In all cases that I've encountered where latexmk does more runs of *latex than I expected, I've found that latexmk is doing the extra runs for good reason. Only with detailed investigation of the situation can one know what the root causes are, and what to do about it.
By looking at the output from running latexmk on the OP's file, I find:

Before each extra run, latexmk says it is going to do another compilation because the .aux file has changed since before the previous compilation.  The changes clearly have at least the potential to change the output.
The output from every compilation includes the warning: LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.  That surely supports latexmk's decision that another compilation is needed.
At the end of its work, latexmk gives an error/warning: Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'tmp': 'pdflatex' needed too many passes.  That indicates that latexmk would have done even more runs if you'd set $max_repeat to a larger value than its default.

I tried running pdflatex many times on the document (without using latexmk).  Everytime, the aux file changed.  The changes were in lines like
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid24}{12970257}{821386}

after run 5, and
\pgfsyspdfmark {pgfid24}{12996471}{847600}

after run 6.  The second and third arguments of \pdfsyspdfmark change after every run.
I had a quick look at the source code for the relevant part of the tikz and pgf packages, where \pgfsyspdfmark is defined (in texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer).  That indicates that the two always-changing arguments are the coordinates of the position of some point (in units of scaled points).  That suggests that the positions of some objects in the pdf file change after every run, and that contrary to the appearance in a pdf viewer, the pdf file never properly stabilizes.
So latexmk is behaving correctly.  There is effectively an infinite loop, from which latexmk escapes because of its limit on the number of compilations.
This strongly suggests that there is a bug somewhere in one of the packages used by the document that prevents the position of entities in the pdf file from stabilizing.

Thanks a lot for the investigation. I suspect the tikzmark library to be guilty. I will report the bug to its developer.

Thanks also for latexmk. :-)

Issue opened here : https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark/issues/18 .

For what it's worth, when I commented out the line remember picture, in main.sty, the problem with excess runs of pdflatex disappeared, without any visible change in the pdf output.

I have reported this in the bug issue.

TL;DR: you missed out the overlay option on your tikzpicture environment that references the locations saved using tikzmark.

It's a good thing that I knew what the problem was likely to be with this one, as it takes a long time for it to show up in the document! Here are screenshots of compilation number 2 and number 126. I'll explain the red dots in a moment, but you can see the key difference in the space between the last line and the next line of text.


To understand the problem, you need to recall how TeX works. It puts content in boxes and then places those boxes on the page. When the placement occurs, the boxes are fixed. So a box cannot know where it will end up. What can happen is that when the box has been positioned then that position is recorded to the aux file, whereupon the box can know where it was last time. So long as the box doesn't change location, this is fine. But if the box does something with that information which causes its location to change then there is the potential to have a situation where its location never stabilises (not technically a loop since it might never repeat).
That's what's happening here.
It's very subtle, mainly due to the \llap which sort-of-but-not-really tries to achieve the same effect as the overlay key, but each tikzpicture is in a slightly different place on each run, and that causes the tikzpictures on the next run to be slightly different as well, until after about 100 runs then the change in location is enough to cause a visible effect.
So what is causing this? Let's look at how tikzmark works. Very simply, it records the coordinates of its location on each run. Now the (pic cs: ...) makes that location available to a tikzpicture. But, it can't do that as raw coordinates because the tikzpicture doesn't know where it is. So we need to put the remember picture on that tikzpicture. This means that it knows where it was last run, and it can then use that information to work out where the tikzmark is relative to its own internal coordinate system, assuming that both the tikzmark and tikzpicture are still in the same locations.
But now without the overlay key then the box for that tikzpicture will be made large enough to contain the coordinate that TikZ has just calculated. As the tikzmark was outside that box on the previous run, this means that the box for the tikzpicture is now larger than it was on the previous run, and so will be located in a different place.
In the screenshots above, I've added code to put a red dot at the origin of the tikzpicture coordinate system. It moves by a very tiny amount on each compilation, so small that you don't notice that the lines are slightly in the wrong place (since they are based on where it was previously). But anything keeping tabs on the aux file notices, and after about 100 compilations so will you.
My guess is that you took out the overlay option and put in the \llap because you wanted to leave enough vertical space for all of the lines. This is something that can get quite complicated, but fortunately is something I've had occasion to think about before (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/722197/86, the documentation referenced there hasn't made it into the CTAN version but is on github, and the method works with current tikzmark anyway).
In fact, since you calculate the required depth in your macro this doesn't need anything complicated. A simple line will do:
\tikz[remember picture,baseline={(0,0)}] {\path (0,\nubvoffset*\unitht);}%

Indeed, someone with a little more familiarity with the \rule command could convert that to a suitable \rule, but the first thing I tried didn't work so I gave up.
Here's my code (including the bit that saves the compilation number to the aux file, just in case that's helpful):
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/730287/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newlength{\unitht}
\setlength{\unitht}{.8ex}

\newcommand{\nubpre}{usecase-A}
\newcommand{\nubdepth}{0}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nub}{mm}{%
  \tikzmark{a\nubpre#1} % 
    #2                  % 
  \tikzmark{b\nubpre#1} % 
  %
  \pgfmathsetmacro\nubvoffset{#1 - \nubdepth}%
  %
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
      remember picture,
      overlay,
      baseline = (current bounding box.north)
    ]
      \draw (pic cs:a\nubpre#1)            
              --++ (0,\nubvoffset*\unitht) 
              -|                           
              (pic cs:b\nubpre#1);
              \fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline={(0,0)}] {\path (0,\nubvoffset*\unitht);}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g__compilations_int
\int_gincr:N \g__compilations_int
\NewDocumentCommand\RestoreCompilations {m}
{
  \int_gset:Nn \g__compilations_int {#1}
  \int_gincr:N \g__compilations_int
}

\NewDocumentCommand\NumberOfCompilations {}
{
  \int_use:N \g__compilations_int
}

\hook_gput_code:nnn {enddocument} {compilations}
{
  \iow_now:ce {@auxout}
  {
    \exp_not:N \RestoreCompilations { \int_use:N \g__compilations_int }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\nubdepth}{6}

$ \nub{1}{
    11 + \nub{2}{
      12 + \nub{3}{
        13 + \nub{4}{
          14 + \nub{5}{15 + 16} +
          17} +
        18} +
      19} +
    20}
= 31 \times 5
= 155$

Compilation number: \NumberOfCompilations

\end{document}



Thanks a lot for this instructive answer.

Here is a solution using only TeX primitive : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/730197/6880 .
